# Не корректное перелистывание слайдов Swiper.js

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper

Не получается корректно перелистывать слайды при работе с Swiper.js
Структура стандартная. Код js:

```html
    const mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        spaceBetween: 60,
        centeredSlides: true,
        centeredSlidesBounds: true,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        effect: 'coverflow',
        coverflowEffect: {
            rotate: 30,
            slideShadows: false,
          },
        keyboard: {
            enabled: true
            }
      });
```

При запуске несколько проблем:

1. Элемент так и не сдвигается в центр (хотя указано) в настройках. loop я убрал, оставив только то, что описано в документации https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#custom-build
2. При сдвиге, он сдвигается на размер всего контейнера как я полагаю. И вообще не нашел варианта, как это можно исправить.

Скрины как получается:

1. Не сдвигается в центр:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Листается не корректно:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел выход:

1. Отцентрировал контейнер свайпера через установку максимального размера окна и марджина. Переназначил overflow. Сделал дополнительный контейнер свайпера, и ограничил у него максимальные размеры шириной окна, а все что сверх - hide.
2. Вторая проблема решилась сама, так как размер контейнера стал в размер слайда, и перелистывание в скрипте работает корректно.